# Drupal6: Where to keep functions/constants needed across multiple modules?

Tags: php, drupal-6, dry

I have a few modules with some functionality overlap. In accordance with DRY, I'd like to move this out to another location, so I will have less code to maintain. Where is the best place to do this? If I just make a module (and make it a dependency of the ones that need it), will I be guaranteed that the constants, functions and variables defined in it will always be available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes that is a fine method. I usually create a module called "common" with a file structure like:

```
common
   common.module //include all the inc files here
   common.date.inc //all functions regarding date/time/etc.
   common.text.inc //all functions regarding text
   common.foo.inc
   ...
   common.js //common javascript stuff, namespacing, etc.
```

I name the functions as ie.

```
    date_unixtime_to_age()
```

and not

```
    common_date_unixtime_to_age()
```

out of convience, but only for this module. All other module I format as

```
    modulename_moduleincfile_functionname()
```

Constants are fine, but try to avoid cluttering the global namespace with variables.

Comment: ok. isn't there some way to only include .inc files if they are necessary?

Comment: Well generally you want your common functions always to be available and the overhead of doing this is insignificant. Inside other modules you can use the "file" setting from hook_menu() to include a file on a per url basis. See http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_menu.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I've done it in the past. It works nicely, the only issue I've had is that sometimes I need to [tweak my utility module's weight (with the Utility module)](http://drupal.org/project/util) so it's included before the modules that depend on it.